# vb.net with SQL Database query all tables while record is not found

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to search all the tables one after another in the specified database for the "num" while "num" is not found. Here is my code that can find "num" (String to find) in Table1, what if record is not found in Table1 and i want to search it in Table2.

```
Module Module1  
Private myConn As SqlConnection
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private myReader As SqlDataReader

Sub Main() 
myConn = New SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=SubsDirectory;" & _
                "Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

 Try
        myConn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Console.ReadKey()
 End Try 

Console.WriteLine(searchNum("aString"))
Console.ReadKey()

End Sub

Public Function searchNum(ByVal num As String) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM Table1 WHERE Field7 like " & num
        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
        myReader.Read()
        result = myReader.GetString(0) & vbTab & myReader.GetString(1)
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Can't you just join the tables into a single query?  If you *really want* to make multiple queries, what exactly is stopping you?  Aside from the glaring SQL injection vulnerability, the code shown demonstrates that you can execute a query.  So what's stopping you from executing another one?

Comment: myReader.HasRows will tell you if a match was found.  A While loop can be used to search each table until you find one with a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is a way to determine if a match was found for your query.  You can use myReader.HasRows for that (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)).  Combine that with a loop of some kind and I think you've solved your problem.  This function might be what you're after:

```
Public Function searchNum(ByVal num As String) As String
    Dim tablesToSearch = {"Table1", "Table2", "Table3"}
    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand

    For Each tableName in tablesToSearch
        myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM " & tableName & " WHERE Field7 like " & num
        myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()
        If myReader.HasRows
            myReader.Read()
            Dim result = myReader.GetString(0) & vbTab & myReader.GetString(1)
            myReader.Close()
            Return result
        End If
        myReader.Close()
    Next

    Return ""
End Function
```